# Logging hibernate SQL using log4j

Tags: sql, hibernate, logging, log4j

I am using hibernate and I am trying to log all the SQL that hibernate automatically generates to the console so that i can see if there is an error in my mapping. I am using log4j so i am trying to use

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ALL, SQL_APPENDER
```

to display all the SQL that hibernate is using but this is not working. I have added this line of code to my `log4j.properties` file but it is not working! am i forgetting something or doing something wrong

i want to display something like this

```
Hibernate: INSERT INTO mkyong.stock_transaction (CHANGE, CLOSE, DATE, OPEN, STOCK_ID, VOLUME) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. Instead of using

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ALL, SQL_APPENDER
```

in my `log4j.properties` file it should be

```
log4j.category.org.hibernate.SQL = ALL
```